# Constructor chaining not using default values of class members?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, constructor, constructor-chaining

I have two classes Unit and Archer. Archer inherits from unit. I tried to use constructor chaining to set the stats for the base class but the stats seem to be set to zero if I use the following code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Unit{
    int damage = 0;
    int curHp = 0;
    int maxHp = 1;
    int range = 0;
    int cost = 0;

public:
    Unit(int _damage,int _maxHp,int _range,
         int _cost){
        damage = _damage;
        curHp = maxHp = _maxHp;
        range = _range;
        cost = _cost;
    }

    int getCost(){
        return cost;
    }
};

class Archer: public Unit{
    int damage = 25;
    int range = 50;
    int maxHp = 100;
    int cost = 150;
    int stepSize = 25;
    int returnedCoins = 0;
public:
    Archer():Unit(damage,maxHp,range,
                  cost){};
};

int main()
{
    Unit *curUnit =  new Archer();
    cout<< curUnit->getCost()<<endl;;
}
```

The output is 0.If I call Unit's construtor with a value instead of using cost(such as 25), I get the value instead I used. For some reason the base value I set in the archer class does not get used at all.

Also, I'm kind of new to OOP so I think I might be doing this the wrong way. I'd be happy if someone could show me the proper way to do this.

Comment: You need to turn up your compiler warnings. [they would tell you something bad is happening](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a496b35caddac76b)

Comment: Ah I had a feeling that it's be something like this. Is there any way I can set the values base classes stats to equal to archer's stats when I call the constructor?

Comment: you need to remove members damage...cost from Archer class.

Comment: @Arturo The constructor is specifically there to set the members. Just tell it the values to set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a non-starter

```
class Archer: public Unit{
    int damage = 25;
    int range = 50;
    int maxHp = 100;
    int cost = 150;
    int stepSize = 25;
    int returnedCoins = 0;
public:
    Archer():Unit(damage,maxHp,range,
                  cost){};
};
```

Bases are initialized *before* the members of your class. And speaking of which, you are duplicating the same members for no reason. Just pass those as arguments:

```
class Archer: public Unit{
    int stepSize = 25;
    int returnedCoins = 0;
public:
    Archer():Unit(25,100,50,
                  150){};
};
```

If your goal was to just give those values meaningful names, you can make them static class constants:

```
class Archer: public Unit{
    static constexpr int damage = 25;
    static constexpr int range = 50;
    static constexpr int maxHp = 100;
    static constexpr int cost = 150;

    int stepSize = 25;
    int returnedCoins = 0;
public:
    Archer():Unit(damage,maxHp,range,
                  cost){};
};
```

Comment: Thanks. I duplicated the members since doing it the way you mentioned makes it kind of unclear what each of the values I'm passing in represent. Is the duplication still a bad thing to do in that case?

Comment: @Arturo - The duplicated ones are completely independent of the base classes members. They hold different values and have their own address inside the complete object. If you just want to name them meaningfully, I can edit a solution to that. A moment.

Comment: @StoryTeller Perhaps name those `constexpr` something else to avoid any confusion with the inherited members.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux - I don't find it confusing to be honest. The base class members are inaccessible anyway, and ultimately it's `Archer::damage` vs `Unit::damage`.